# Why a protected method of parent class in one package cannot be accessed using the parent reference in its child class which is in different package

Tags: java, package, protected

Why a protected method of parent class in one package cannot be accessed using the parent reference in its child class which is in different package.
[A.java][[]][[](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSOcZ.jpg)1][1]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9fGz.jpg)

Comment: Have a look at this cheat sheet: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33627846/276052

Answer (score 0):

The scope of protected is within the package. You can't access it from another package, even if you have an instance of the class.

Scope table from Oracle [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

```
Modifier    Class   Package Subclass    World
public      Y       Y       Y           Y
protected   Y       Y       Y           N
no modifier Y       Y       N           N
private     Y       N       N           N
```

Answer (score 0):

Its by convention - that is what `protected` is defined to do. Protected members in the child class only through inheritance. No other way.

Lets assume we can access the protected member in the child class which is in a different package using parent class instance.

Now, how would you differentiate in your child class - if the member was declared `public` or `protected`? Also, if it is accessible using the parent instance, then why access it only from child class? It should be accessible from anywhere using parent class instance.

I hope, if you ask these questions to yourself - it will all start making sense.